# delete odd/even rows from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Can we delete every other (odd/even manner) row from NSMutable array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSMutableArray's -removeObjectsAtIndexes: to remove all objects at specific indices at once:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;
NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [[[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init] autorelease];
// Some loop to populate 'indexes' with the indices of the odd/even items

[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Comment: ya i am doing with for loop--i mean is there any ready to use function or command..?

Comment: No, you have to construct an NSIndexSet by hand. If you're using a loop without an NSIndexSet to remove the items sequentially, you'll find that you won't be removing the correct items (as soon as you remove one, the indices of the others will change).

Comment: `newArray = [ array objectsAtIndexes:[ array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL( id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL * stop){ return (index & 1) == 0 ; } ] ] ;`